# Inserting into a table where you have a foreign key and want it to be inserted from another table

Tags: php, mysql, visual-studio-code, foreign-keys, primary-key

Hello I have this query where I want to insert some data and I have a foreign key I want it to be inserted from the other table because of its a primary key there

here's my code:

```
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "company");
$st = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO reservations(customer_id,players_number,res_date) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$st->bind_param("iii", $_POST["players_number"], $_POST["res_date"], $_GET["id"]);
$st->execute();
header('Location: http://localhost/tech/calendar.php');
```

the table I want to insert to is called reservations and the customer_id must come from the customer's table where there it's the primary key
and I have a form under this code which leads to the same page to get to the code above

[image]

**Thanks in advance!**

when I go to the calendar of the customer I have this url

[image]

when I press the add reservation button it has the id in the url using $_GET method

[image]

This is the error I get:

[image]

I'm sorry if it's not a very clear question but I'm new to this and doing my Internship with lots of tasks where i got to the point of desperate!!

Comment: How are you deciding what `customer_id` you want to insert?

Comment: there's a button to add reservation with $_GET['id'] to get the customer_id, i'll add it in the question

Comment: So what's the problem? If you have the id and you know that it exists in the `customer` table then you can just insert it in the FK column

Comment: Also, I'm not especially familiar with PHP but it looks to me as if you're replacing the `customer_id` value param with `players_number`. Should your `bind_param()` not be in the same order as the columns in the insert?

Comment: well if i put it this way 
                        $st->bind_param("iii", $_POST["customer_id"] , $_POST["players_number"], $_POST["res_date"], $_GET["id"]); you meant? it's not getting PK this way I have no idea what's wrong

Comment: `$_GET["id"]` returns the primary key for the customer, correct? Which needs to be the foreign key in `reservations`?

Comment: correct, i just saw what you're talking about now the code is in the right order, $st->bind_param("iii",  $_GET["id"],$_POST["players_number"], $_POST["res_date"]); but still there's an error which I cant find